# How to run maven tests in gitlab ci without rebuilding the project?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

I created a Maven Spring boot project. In the build job I want to only build the project without tests. In the test stage I want to run unit tests and use the build from the build stage, so no new build in test stage. The problem is that mvn runs a build again in the test stage.

```
image: maven:3.8-jdk-11

stages:          
  - build
  - test

build-job:       
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target

test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
```

If it runs a build in the test stage again, then the build stage wouldnt be necessary. But I want separate stages for both to better separate and see where something goes wrong.

Comment: Simply use `mvn verify` as a single step anything else does not make sense... You will see if something goes wrong... Have you tried that on your local machine in the console first to see the results... Also see the detailed answer here..

Comment: @khmarbaise `mvn verify` as CI entry point sounds too drastic, however I agree it is more promising to start from `mvn verify` to understand what steps could be delegated to CI.

Comment: What is to drastic ?

Comment: In general, Devs do not want to deal with it infra, DevOps do not want to deal with project code, moreover they do not want to learn IT (I always dreamed to work for company where that is not true, but no luck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in my opinion the idea to split build process into different stages might look attractive but actually does not have any practical benefits, especially in your case when you are trying to split packaging into compile, test and, probably, package stages. Think about following:

- in case of pull request pipeline what we actually need to get is:

  - the answer whether the changes from pull request do actually work, i.e. yes or no
  - reports from other tools (code coverage, static code analysis, etc)
  - build logs to analyse failures
- in case of release pipeline we also expect to get artifacts deployed into DML

Everything mentioned above is already covered by maven - there is no practical reason to split `mvn package` into separate parts, moreover everything in maven project till `verify` phase is about the code only - CI should not intervene in `mvn package`.

Now, why do we need stages in CI? Obviously we need stages when our CI process somehow depends on environment, i.e. when we are performing build against different platforms or we would like to run external tools, however **there is no place for external tools till `verify` phase**.

At second, if you really want to split `mvn package` into separate stages the options are following:

- configure maven plugins to skip execution relying on maven/system properties, most of maven plugins have such capability, e.g. to skip compile you may pass `-Dmaven.main.skip=true` to command line or setup something like `<skipMain>my.cool.property</skipMain>` and pass `-Dmy.cool.property=true`
- as previous one, but consolidate properties in maven profiles
- reconstruct maven lifecycle phase manually, for example in you case it might look something like: `mvn resources:testResources compiler:testCompile surefire:test`

However, all of those options look very poor from my perspective due to following considerations:

- it is very complex and ugly
- it requires to keep in sync CI definition and maven poms

Comment: This: `however there is no place for external tools till verify phase.` why? You can bind different plugins into the life cycle?

Comment: mvn plugins are a part of mvn lifecycle, my expectation is: if I checkout project code from version control, having java and maven installed is enough to build project artifacts and run unit tests.

Comment: If you need special things you can write your own plugin (activate them for example by profiles/properties etc.)...but most of the time not necessary. You can use things like JUnit Jupiter Extensions (Testcontainers for example) to start other services (inside docker) or using other extensions to start otherthings, which are used/needed during integration- or end-to-end tests.

Comment: oh, I got your point - it was about `verify` phase... I have not doubts about `package` but `verify` is arguable: we tried both approaches (manage it infra via CI and via maven/code), and I would say code approach looks more clear from my perspective, but it still does not make me happy, I would prefer to have some universal API to manage it infra, at first glance ability to send commands from code/maven to CI would be a good starting point.